# Delete Highchart top line with heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to remove the line indicated by the line in the image below:

[image]

Below you can see the chart options, or you can try it in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mszr264b/1/:

```
{
   "chart":{
      "type":"heatmap",
      "style":{
         "fontFamily":"Open Sans, sans-serif"
      },
      "backgroundColor":"transparent"
   },
   "tooltip":{
      "enabled":false
   },
   "title":{
      "style":{
         "display":"none"
      }
   },
   "credits":{
      "enabled":false
   },
   "plotOptions":{
      "series":{
         "dataLabels":{
            "style":{
               "textOutline":false
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "xAxis":{
      "categories":[
         "07:00",
         "08:00",
         "09:00",
         "10:00",
         "11:00",
         "12:00",
         "13:00",
         "14:00",
         "15:00",
         "16:00",
         "17:00",
         "18:00",
         "19:00",
         "20:00",
         "21:00",
         "22:00",
         "23:00"
      ]
   },
   "yAxis":{
      "categories":[
         "D",
         "L",
         "M",
         "M",
         "G",
         "V",
         "S"
      ],
      "title":null
   },
   "colorAxis":{
      "min":0,
      "minColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "maxColor":"#c0392b"
   },
   "legend":{
      "enabled":false
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "borderWidth":1,
         "data":[
            [
               0,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               1,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               2,
               0,
               5
            ],
            [
               3,
               0,
               15
            ],
            [
               4,
               0,
               18
            ],
            [
               5,
               0,
               12
            ],
            [
               6,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               7,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               8,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               9,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               10,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               11,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               12,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               13,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               14,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               0,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               1,
               35
            ],
            [
               1,
               1,
               698
            ],
            [
               2,
               1,
               254
            ],
            [
               3,
               1,
               518
            ],
            [
               4,
               1,
               485
            ],
            [
               5,
               1,
               219
            ],
            [
               6,
               1,
               171
            ],
            [
               7,
               1,
               227
            ],
            [
               8,
               1,
               1062
            ],
            [
               9,
               1,
               1119
            ],
            [
               10,
               1,
               192
            ],
            [
               11,
               1,
               408
            ],
            [
               12,
               1,
               222
            ],
            [
               13,
               1,
               118
            ],
            [
               14,
               1,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               1,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               1,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               2,
               4
            ],
            [
               1,
               2,
               19
            ],
            [
               2,
               2,
               12
            ],
            [
               3,
               2,
               33
            ],
            [
               4,
               2,
               19
            ],
            [
               5,
               2,
               10
            ],
            [
               6,
               2,
               4
            ],
            [
               7,
               2,
               3
            ],
            [
               8,
               2,
               6
            ],
            [
               9,
               2,
               7
            ],
            [
               10,
               2,
               2
            ],
            [
               11,
               2,
               1
            ],
            [
               12,
               2,
               1
            ],
            [
               13,
               2,
               1
            ],
            [
               14,
               2,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               2,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               2,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               3,
               ""
            ],
            [
               1,
               3,
               12
            ],
            [
               2,
               3,
               6
            ],
            [
               3,
               3,
               5
            ],
            [
               4,
               3,
               6
            ],
            [
               5,
               3,
               7
            ],
            [
               6,
               3,
               1
            ],
            [
               7,
               3,
               2
            ],
            [
               8,
               3,
               3
            ],
            [
               9,
               3,
               1
            ],
            [
               10,
               3,
               1
            ],
            [
               11,
               3,
               4
            ],
            [
               12,
               3,
               1
            ],
            [
               13,
               3,
               ""
            ],
            [
               14,
               3,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               3,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               3,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               4,
               4
            ],
            [
               1,
               4,
               4
            ],
            [
               2,
               4,
               2
            ],
            [
               3,
               4,
               3
            ],
            [
               4,
               4,
               2
            ],
            [
               5,
               4,
               1
            ],
            [
               6,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               7,
               4,
               1
            ],
            [
               8,
               4,
               1
            ],
            [
               9,
               4,
               2
            ],
            [
               10,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               11,
               4,
               1
            ],
            [
               12,
               4,
               1
            ],
            [
               13,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               14,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               4,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               1,
               5,
               3
            ],
            [
               2,
               5,
               4
            ],
            [
               3,
               5,
               3
            ],
            [
               4,
               5,
               3
            ],
            [
               5,
               5,
               3
            ],
            [
               6,
               5,
               2
            ],
            [
               7,
               5,
               1
            ],
            [
               8,
               5,
               1
            ],
            [
               9,
               5,
               1
            ],
            [
               10,
               5,
               2
            ],
            [
               11,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               12,
               5,
               1
            ],
            [
               13,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               14,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               5,
               ""
            ],
            [
               0,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               1,
               6,
               11
            ],
            [
               2,
               6,
               21
            ],
            [
               3,
               6,
               5
            ],
            [
               4,
               6,
               4
            ],
            [
               5,
               6,
               1
            ],
            [
               6,
               6,
               1
            ],
            [
               7,
               6,
               1
            ],
            [
               8,
               6,
               2
            ],
            [
               9,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               10,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               11,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               12,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               13,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               14,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               15,
               6,
               ""
            ],
            [
               16,
               6,
               ""
            ]
         ],
         "color":"white"
      }
   ]
}
```

Anyone know how can I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `yAxis` with [gridLineWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth)

[image]

```
 "yAxis":{
  "categories":[
     "D",
     "L",
     "M",
     "M",
     "G",
     "V",
     "S"
  ],
  gridLineWidth: 0, //added 
  "title":null
```

},

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ktg2q55/) Demo